# Is there a way to get a string for the classifications of the model from a TensorBuffer?

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite

Using this code, is there a way to get a string for it? I wanted to get the classes TensorBuffer object as a string to use in my app.

```
try {
    SsdMobilenetV11Metadata1 model = SsdMobilenetV11Metadata1.newInstance(context);

    // Creates inputs for reference.
    TensorImage image = TensorImage.fromBitmap(bitmap);

    // Runs model inference and gets result.
    SsdMobilenetV11Metadata1.Outputs outputs = model.process(image);
    TensorBuffer locations = outputs.getLocationsAsTensorBuffer();
    TensorBuffer classes = outputs.getClassesAsTensorBuffer();
    TensorBuffer scores = outputs.getScoresAsTensorBuffer();
    TensorBuffer numberOfDetections = outputs.getNumberOfDetectionsAsTensorBuffer();

    // Releases model resources if no longer used.
    model.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Handle the exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The model needs to do post processing. The classes variable will have the indices of the detected classes. If you have a label list, the label name can be obtained by accessing the indices, stored the classes variable.